# How do you pass data between models in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller and I current have it using redirect going to another controller, I know I can pass data around using the :query...

Is there any way I can do this without the use of http as I'm finding it impossible to send a hash using http.

I cant find this information any where, what is the most common way of sharing data (slash sending) data from one controller to another?

please help been working on this for hours, btw am new to RoR

Comment: What are you trying to send and why? Giving a brief description of what you're actually trying to accomplish is helpful.

Comment: trying to send a hash of information from one controller to another, I am making templates which can be reused, all configuration for the template is stored in the hash. So my software which has more then 30 screens will basically run with only 4 templates (the screens are very similar with different data)

Comment: A controller should never talk to another controller. Also, your question title refers to models, but your description (and comment) refers to controllers.

Comment: Also what do you mean "templates"? Do you mean HTML views?

Comment: You may render another controller's view with the `render` method, e.g. `render controller: :another, action: :show`. You may refactor common parts of two controllers into a module. You should never pass data between controllers in Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are redirecting the browser, you will have to use the query option as redirect actually tells the browser to make another request to a different path.

If you just want to render the other controllers action you could call:

```
render :template=>"path to view you want to render"
```

As for actually calling the other action?  You could distill (refactor) the logic into a lib and call the same logic from both controllers, then use the same view for both..

Comment: I think it's a bit of a smell to render the view from an entirely unrelated controller.

Comment: I disagree, i feel it plays right into the concept of DRY.  There is no reason you can't use the same view for multiple actions.  That is why the render :template option exists. Perhaps it would be better to move the view into a folder named views/shared

Comment: Yes moving it into some sort of shared folder is best. But rendering a view that is, based on the directory conventions, solely tied to a different controller is misleading. Also, the `:template` is not needed, just passing the string with the path is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer, I may have not been specific enough with the question. But you can pass a hash using the query string; which obviously (now that I think of it) converts it to a string duh. so I just use `eval` in the receiving hash,

`eval(@params['inputData']` which gives me the hash.